# Bluetooth keyboard disconnecting 6.5.0-21 kernel

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, bluetooth

My logi MX Keys Mini keyboard has been working well for a year or so and suddenly started disconnecting from Bluetooth. I can pair it but it disconnects within 5 seconds.

The message I get from `journalctl -u bluetooth | tail` is:

> bluetoothd[6671]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for DE:BC:97:80:A4:1C

`BLuetoothctl` shows the error

> [CHG] Device DE:BC:97:80:A4:1C Connected: no Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled

I tried removing the keyboard, clearing the bluetooth cache and using previous kernel version but nothing works. Also tried with a different keyboard and the same keeps happening. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, kernel 6.5.0-21.

Does anyone have any clue what else I could try?

Comment: Have you tried deleting `/var/lib/bluetooth` , rebooting, then re-pairing? I also assume you didn't change `/etc/bluetooth`

Comment: I just tried, but it would still keep disconnecting with the same error from `bluetoothctl`
```[CHG] Device DD:98:97:01:80:8B Connected: no 
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled```